# Dialog position in android

Tags: android

I am creating a store map where image is coming from the sever. I have co-ordinate of specific position of product item. I am showing dialog on different markers which I have drawn through canvas.
Dialog shows perfect when I click over makers, But when I scroll the image & click the marker again, dialog position also changes every-time. Is there any solution for perfect positioning of dialog on image scroll?
Thank you.

**main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#2567B3" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="First Floor"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"   />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/back1"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:background="@drawable/back" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_list"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
             />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.shopping.PaintView
                android:id="@+id/paint_view"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/test" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements OnTouchListener {

    static float mX,mY,mX1,mY1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Getting reference to PaintView
        PaintView paintView = (PaintView) findViewById(R.id.paint_view);
        paintView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        backclick();
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Dialog dialogMarketList = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewList = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,null);
        dialogMarketList.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialogMarketList.setContentView(viewList);

        Window window = dialogMarketList.getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = window.getAttributes();
        wmlp.gravity = Gravity.START | Gravity.TOP;
        wmlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
        window.setAttributes(wmlp);

        TextView header = (TextView) viewList.findViewById(R.id.header);




        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // // Getting X & Y coordinate
            int offers[] = { 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 };
            int pointx[] = { 47, 338, 396, 52, 49, 387, 468, 455, 217, 231 };
            int pointy[] = { 77, 59, 297, 294, 564, 534, 56, 407, 478, 187 };
            int distance = 35;
             mX = event.getX();
             mY = event.getY();



            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { 

                if (mX > pointx[i] - distance && mX < pointx[i] + distance && mY >pointy[i] - distance && mY < pointy[i] + distance) {


                    if (offers[i] == 0){
                        header.setText("floor: 1" + "\nShelf: Top"
                                + "\nPosition: Right");
                        wmlp.x = (int) mX; // x position
                        wmlp.y = (int) mY; // y position
                    }

                    else {
                            header.setText("floor: 2" + "\nShelf: Top"
                                + "\nPosition: Right" + "\nOffer:10% discount");
                            wmlp.x = (int) mX; // x position
                            wmlp.y = (int) mY; // y position
                    }

                    dialogMarketList.show();

                }
            }
            break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**PaintView.java**

```
    public class PaintView extends View {
        int offers[]={0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0};
        Paint mPaint;
        float mX[]={47,338,396,52,49,387,468,455,217,231};
        float mY[]={77,59,297,294,564,534,56,407,478,187};  
        TextView mTVCoordinates;
        // ---add the marker---
        Bitmap marker1;
        Bitmap marker2;
        public PaintView(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet){
            super(context,attributeSet);

        /** Initializing the variables */
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mTVCoordinates = null;

        marker1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.blue);
        marker2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.red);  
    }   
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {      
        super.onDraw(canvas);



    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {       
        if(offers[i]==0)
        {   canvas.drawBitmap(marker1,mX[i], mY[i], null);
            invalidate();
        }
        else
        {   canvas.drawBitmap(marker2, mX[i], mY[i], null);
            invalidate();   
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You need to elaborate this question. Above explanation is not making any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to show dialog at the bottom of the screen:

```
Dialog dlg = <code to create custom dialog>;

Window window = dlg.getWindow();
WindowManager.LayoutParams wlp = window.getAttributes();

wlp.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
wlp.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND;
window.setAttributes(wlp);
```

This code also prevents android from dimming the background of the dialog, if you need it. You should be able to change the gravity parameter to move the dialog about

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the anchor of the dialog to the your marker.Google maps also uses the anchors to display the marker window for the markers.

Here's a way to set the anchor.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);

button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

hope it helps